# youtube-dl download autotranslate subs

Tags: networking, command-line, youtube-dl, video-subtitles

I would like to download auto-generated subtitles with `youtube-dl`
as follows

```
$ youtube-dl --write-auto-sub \
             --skip-download \
             https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbLEf4HR74E
```

It downloads file `The habits of happiness _ Matthieu Ricard-vbLEf4HR74E.en.vtt` which is not auto-generated subtitles, it contains the word `coke box` instead of `Coca-Cola tins`.

How to download the right file?

Comment: which version do you use?

Comment: @Jaleks 2018.06.14

Comment: `youtube-dl **--write-sub** --skip-download _--sub-lang=en_ "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbLEf4HR74E" ` does something looking OK for my version 2017.05.18.1-1. youtube-dl tells me "Couldn't find automatic captions for vbLEf4HR74E" for `--write-auto-sub`

Comment: @Jaleks Your command also doesn't download autogenerated subtitles, but human-translated subtitles instead (with the word "coke box"). You need to [update youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-update-youtube-dl)

Comment: Different versions - different results. I get "Coca-cola tins"…

Comment: I'm sorry you're right. I should use --write-sub instead of --write-auto-sub. It works now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```bsh
youtube-dl --write-sub \
           --skip-download \
           --sub-lang=en \
           "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbLEf4HR74E"
```

does something looking OK on version `2017.05.18.1-1`.

youtube-dl says `Couldn't find automatic captions for vbLEf4HR74E` with `--write-auto-sub` but `--write-sub` with a selected language `--sub-lang=en` seems to work.

Comment: Yes, sometimes works `--write-sub` and sometimes works `--write-auto-sub` (when human-translated subtitles are missing)